# How to add user input with commas into database using wpdb

Tags: php, sql, ajax, wordpress

I am using a form submitted to a PHP script via AJAX which in turn uses wpdb update to alter a database record.

Everything works perfectly except when input is entered into a textarea that contains a comma.

Are there additional steps I need to take to allow commas to be added to the database successfully using wpdb update?

I have searched the internet for an answer to this question but for the most part people are more interested in removing or changing commas rather than preserving them!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide more information on the issue you are encountering? What do you mean that it does not work perfectly? Is the error with Javascript, PHP, or your MySQL query?

Comment: Hi there, when I add input that contains a comma the database record does not get updated and the PHP script that processes the data does not return anything to the AJAX call. If I remove the comma from the input the database is updated and the script returns a success message as expected so the issue is definitely the comma in the content of the user input. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, thanks again for taking the time to read my question and respond, I have figured out what the problem was... I was sending the data to the PHP script as a comma delimited string and so when passed a string value that contained a comma it would cause it to break. Changed the delimiter and problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the problem was... I was sending the data to the PHP script as a comma delimited string and so when passed a string value that contained a comma it would cause it to break. Changed the delimiter and problem solved :)